# WPF data context scenario

Tags: wpf, mvvm-toolkit

I have a user control in XAML code (a data grid) with this databind statement:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" x:Name="lvItems"
```

I use this user control in a presenter class where I istantiate a modelview  class and set datacontext to an object in my view

...so MyCollection object is defined in may view class and not in the code behind of my control

but I Want to access this MyCollection property from codebehind because I want to implement a button event that filter my collection source

how can I access to MyCollection in codebehind or where i wrong...?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like that?

put this at your button click event or the button command

```
var yourModelView = this.DataContext as IYourModelView;
if (yourModelView != null) {
  var yourColl = yourModelView.MyCollection;
  // do something with this collection
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public IYourModelView
{
  ICollection MyCollection {get; set;}
}

public class YourModelView1 : IYourModelView
{}

public class YourModelView2 : IYourModelView
{}
```

hope this helps

Comment: @guton yes, i think, why not?

Comment: I mean that this control is used by many view model  if I cast for one of this all work ..but ...I dont know witch one... ...the control serve many view model (sorry for my english)

Comment: ...in the code behind of control i don't know wich view model uses that control....

Comment: @guton try using a interface IYourModelView wiht the collection property MyCollection, look at my changed answer

Comment: ...in my interface I ideally dont would have ever a collection ..i use ayende effetcus model see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx

Comment: I mean that I can have a modelview not based on a collection